# Can my Linux virtual machine infect other computers that share my Wi-Fi network?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, malware

I’ve installed Linux Mint 18 in a VirtualBox VM for casual web browsing purposes. I have disabled shared folders and the shared clipboard, but I am concerned that if the VM becomes infected, malware could spread to other computers that share my Wi-Fi network (including my host computer). I have read that VM to host infection is very rare, but I am unsure what extra security steps may be required to make the VM more securely isolated.

Are my concerns warranted? If so, what extra security steps do I need to take? How can I better isolate the VM or protect other computers in my network from unintentionally becoming infected?

For reference, my host OS is macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, consider enabling "AP Isolation" or "Client isolation" on your wireless AP. This will prevent your VM from accessing other systems on your network entirely. Thats about the best you can do from a generic perspective.

First, you must understand that there are several general families of malware used for initial infection of a machine, including Viruses, Worms, and Trojan's, Other types, like root/bootkits, information stealers, etc, are generally installed after or as a direct result of initial infection.

Of the three vectors, only Viruses and Worms can spread to other machines, like an infection. Trojans require a framework for distribution like drive-by-download attacks. Usually Trojans require user actions in order to download and run on a system. Of particular interest to your situation, do not install any third party drivers in the VM, to avoid theoretical blue/purple pill exploits.

Viruses are malcode that targets applications like email clients, which have their own means for communicating over the network. The virus causes the program to malfunction in such a way that the application itself infects other computers. Old-fashion email viruses worked this way. The key here though, is that Viruses are almost extinct; killed by automatic upgrade features included in almost all applications these days.

Worms are malcode that exploit vulnerabilities in the components of the operating system which interact with other computers (like the network stack for a given protocol, or the USB autoplay). It takes a very special vulnerability to have a "wormable" exploit, so these days (especially with auto-updating OSs) wormable 0-day exploits are pretty rare. At least for PCs; so-called Internet-of-Things (IoT) devices are the new playground for worms and automated attacks on network services, as they rarely (if ever) get software/firmware updates.

So, as you stated, there is very little risk of cross infection, unless you become a target of a very motivated actor, in which case, nothing we advise here is sufficient anyway. Keep your software up to date, avoid any third party software unless its very reputable, run your within VM as a user for everything but admin tasks, and generally avoid the deep dark underbelly of the internet, and you will be fine from most automated attacks.